# How can I add background music in a windows form for c++?

Tags: windows, forms, background, c++-cli

I've tried a many different ways but nothing works.

I've already marked the windows media player option in the COM section, and I have the WMPLib library added.

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace WMPLib;

namespace {
    bool turno =true; // true= X false = O
        int contador=0;
}
/// <summary>
/// Resumen de MyForm
/// </summary>
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
    **WindowsMediaPlayer^ player = gcnew WindowsMediaPlayer();**
  //This is the problem i have an error in the equal sign 
public:
    MyForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

         }
```

Comment: It is C++/CLI, **not** C++. Don't tag unnecessary tags.

Comment: Use the Form designer. Drag a media player from the toolbox onto the form and that is all.

Comment: and what do i do next?

Comment: If you just want to play a sound it doesn't get easier than [PlaySound()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743680.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

The type is `AxWindowsMediaPlayer`, not `WindowsMediaPlayer`, that is why you get the error.

If you add the player in the *form designer*, you don’t need to create (**genew**) another instance, the designer has created one for you.

Then set the URL property, and then call `play()` method on the `Ctlcontrols` property to play the media.

```
this->axWindowsMediaPlayer1->URL = L"a.wma";
this->axWindowsMediaPlayer1->Ctlcontrols->play();
```

Comment: Although this answer gets a downvote, **it is a valid answer**. Help this helps someone in the future.